# How to enable reset password feature for clients using Kibana dashboard which is hosted on cloud?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have a Kibana dashboard hosted on a cloud, the requirement is to enable a feature which asks the client to reset password after certain period of time along with password matching a certain criteria. The only option I see in the Kibana docs is the command that resets password. But I am looking for a third party plugin that can be integrated with Elasticsearch or Kibana which can ask the client to reset his password on the dashboard along with the security aspects.

Answer (score 1):

In free version of Elasticsearch it's not possible to add expiry date. If you have a license you can use [Kibana SSO](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/kibana-authentication.html).

**2019** - Adding expiry date for password is not possible - https://discuss.elastic.co/t/users-password-policy/190944

**2023** - Adding expiry date for password is not possible - https://discuss.elastic.co/t/expiration-date-password-for-kibana-users/335989

Are you using `Active Directory, LDAP, SAML or OpenID Connection`? If so you can manage it from there. (need to have license)

Another solution can be adding a proxy like NginX in front of the Kibana.